# How to keep n osgi bundle listening to the mqtt broker

Tags: java, osgi, activemq-classic, mqtt, apache-felix

I was able to bundle the ActiveMQ and push it into the Apache Felix context.
But I faced an issue once started playing with it:

Here is the scenario :

1. I created the ActiveMQ bundle inside Apache Felix, I run it and it listens to the needed port.
2. I created the producer bundle and putted all the needed connection and queue creation in the start method.
3. I created the consumer bundle following the same strategy

Once I start the producer, I can see my message sent.

Once I run the consumer it's OK I can see the message received, 
the issue is once I stop the producer bundle and I restart it, I was waiting to get a notification from my consumer bundle getting the new message.. but not, I do have to restart the consumer so it knows about the new message and throw it out.

Do you have an idea on how could I get notified by my bundle once a new message pushed into the broker queue ?

I'm thinking about the multithreading, but I'm not sure, in the activeMq tutos it creates the producers/consumers using threads.
So probably that's the issue..

Do I have to register my bundle in the osgi service registry ?!

```
//this is my start method
// Create a ConnectionFactory
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost");

// Create a Connection
Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();

// Create a Session
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

// Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
Destination destination = session.createQueue("TEST.FOO");

// Create a MessageProducer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);
producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

// Create a messages
String text = "Hello world! From: " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " : " + this.hashCode();
TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(text);

// Tell the producer to send the message
System.out.println("Sent message: "+ message.hashCode() + " : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
producer.send(message);

// Clean up
session.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad indent of the text..

Comment: You can edit your own question (edit link just under the tags)

Comment: I think the problem will rather be on the consumer side. Can you show your consumer code?

Comment: Is the ActiveMQ bundle active?